# WP galleries in posts after import. How do I do it?

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

I moved the website posts with Wp All Export and All import, which worked fine, but many of the posts contained galleries (Wordpresses gallery with [gallery] shortcode).
The problem is that now the galleries do not appear. When editing a post, the shortcode shows the IDs, which have been updated OK, they match the images on the new website, yet nothing appears and it says no images to display.

I use a Divi theme, if that matters.

Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming issue. I'd suggest possibly posting on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com instead, but be sure to take their tour first to see what is acceptable.

Comment: Update the URLs of your images and attachments using a plugin such as Velvet Blues Update URLs. Although, you can rebuild your media library via plugins like Media Sync.

Answer (score 0):

Wp All Export and All import plugin uses XML and CSV and it works fine for posts and pages but has issues with media files. I will suggest to use the native wordpress Import/Export functionality but before you export just install the plugin called "Export media with selected content By Joost de Keijzer" and it will export all the attached and relevant media files along with posts. That way when you upload the XML or CSV file on the new website it will import all the media and images from the old website and you will not have broken images.